# SSRS - How to add a default value to a parameter with Available Values from a query?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, parameters, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have an SSRS report which contains a parameter ID, which will display sales totals for a person with selected ID. I get the options for the parameter by selecting "Get values from a query" under the Parameter's "Available Values" setting. However, in addition to these values, I want the first (default) value in the dropdown to be "All", which will display results for everyone combined. How can I add this hard-coded default to the dropdown list?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to go about this.

I think the better way is to use a **Multi-Value parameter** and letting SSRS do the actual work. You would just need to change where you use the parameter to use it as a multi-value parameter (change `= @PARAMETER` to `IN (@PARAMETER)`).

For the **Default** values, use the same value field as was used for the **Available** Values.

[image]

[image]

The other way is to do it manually by appending an extra row to the parameter's dataset for the < ALL>. First you need to UNION an < ALL> to the data.

```
SELECT '<ALL>' AS EMPLOYEE_ID
UNION
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID
FROM EMPLOYEES
```

For the **Default** value, **Specify** the value `<ALL>`.

Then you change you query or expression to use the EMPLOYEE ID or ALL:

SQL:

```
WHERE (EMPLOYEE_ID = @EMPLOYEE_ID or @EMPLOYEE_ID = '<ALL>')
```

SSRS **Expression**:

```
=IIF(FIELDS!EMPLOYEE_ID.VALUE = Parameters!EMPLOYEE_ID.Value OR Parameters!EMPLOYEE_ID.Value = "<ALL>", 1, 0)
```

**Value:** `1`

Comment: I couldn't get the first solution to work, it didn't seem to really change much. I got the second to work though (with a little but of tinkering, I'll make an edit for the change), thanks :)

Comment: update: Sorry, I had to remove the accepted check, since it doesn't work for me as written. I tried to update the answer since the same code just very slightly changed apparently isn't an acceptable edit. @Hannover Fist, maybe they'll let you change it instead, then I can mark it as accepted

Comment: What change did you need to make? It looks like it should work.

Comment: In the eselect union block of code, it gave me errors as it's written, but if the code above and below the UNION is swapped (ie SELECT '<ALL>' first) it works perfectly

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - the `SELECT ALL` is first in the **UNION** query and it seems to work for me as it is.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be different, but for me it only worked the second way